# Flutter Stripe Payment : StripeSource class missing

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments

I am following [this](https://medium.com/flutterpub/flutter-stripe-firebase-d6299e6f76ef) and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nGBIb5H2_Xg&t=3s) tutorial to integrate stripe payment into my flutter project. Both of these tutorials/examples reference the class `StripeSource` by calling its method

`StripeSource.setPublishableKey("pk_test");`

but this class seems to be missing from the latest stripe package for a flutter. I've added the flutter SDK using `stripe_payment: ^1.0.0` in my `pubspec.yaml` file and other stripe classes are available.

Any help is highly appreciated :-).

Comment: I am facing problem while charging from a specific card how can I do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those tutorial are outdated. The library changed and now it works in a different way. Instead of using `StripeSource`, you should use `StripePayment`.
For example:

```
StripePayment.setOptions(StripeOptions(
                          publishableKey:
                              'YOUR_TEST_PUBLISH_KEY'));
                      StripePayment.paymentRequestWithCardForm(
                              CardFormPaymentRequest())
                          .catchError((e) {
                        print('ERROR ${e.toString()}');
                      }).then((paymentMethod) {
                        //DO SOMETHING WITH YOUR PAYMENT METHOD
                      });
```

**EDIT**

What matters to follow those tutorials, is to optain the 'token'. As it is not very clear and there is not a complete documentation, I want to point out that:
`paymentMethod.id` is equal to the token returned by `StripeSource.addSource()` in the old versions.